# Can we use "Been" without have/has/had?

Tags: sentence-usage

I've never seen "been" been used without have/has/had. But in some songs it appears that they sometime use "been" without have. When I searched on internet the lyrics of some songs, it was actually like "I've been" or "It's been". I always thought that it's not *I been*, it's I've been but recently I saw the lyrics of the song "Forgot about Dre" in which they use it multiple times as:

1. ...But I been low key...
2. ...Sorry Doc but I been crazy...
3. ...ya'll are the reason Dre **ain't been** getting no sleep...

The last sentence is quite confusing. *ain't been* = is not been. Someone told me that we can never use something like *is been*, e.g "I am been" means that somebody is being me.

Please explain me in simple language, what does *I been* mean and when is it used. Please do not explain the grammer, that is verb, noun etc; I am learning English without studying formal grammar.

Comment: I guess that simply for the sake of the rhythm of the verses, an incorrect grammar is in use, but I'm not ready to answer the question.

Comment: @MARamezani "I been", AFAIK is not incorrect grammer. [Here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/28943/3448) they explain what it means. The explaination is quite grammatical there, that's why I've asked this question.

Comment: *I been* is never correct in standard English (i.e., the most common rules of English grammar in the U.S., U.K., and most or all other English-speaking countries), but the "have" in "have been" it is sometimes omitted in non-standard slang speech. Also, this use of "been" (without have/has) appears in the English dialect of [African American Vernacular English (AAVE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English).

Comment: @apsillers If I use _I been_, while communicating with someone who is non-African-American, would they understand what I would try to say.

Comment: @user31782 Yes, they will understand. (They might also assume you speak a different dialect of English than they do.)

Comment: If you look up "ain't in a dictionary, you will find that, though considered non standard by many people, it means not only "am not/is not/are not but also has not/have not".

Comment: By the way, we no longer employ *use to VERB* in the sense "be one's habit or practise" in any tense or construction except the past *used to*, which is pronounced "yoosta" (/justə/).

Comment: @StoneyB What should I use in place of _use to_? Happen to? You say we no longer use it. Has it actualy been used in the past?

Comment: It was common in the 17th century, but declined steadily into the 19th; I don't think I've ever seen a 20th century use. I suggest you say merely "I am learning English without studying formal grammar".

Comment: "aint been" != "is not been", which would be "isn't been" when contracted, although it is not correct of course. "aint" is a slang contraction of "have/has not".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. *Been* is widely used in a number of British and American dialects as an abbreviated form of present perfect *have been/has been*. In some cases the form is established as a dialect standard, in other cases it represents a severe elision of *have been*—/v/ and /b/ are pronounced at exactly the same  point in the mouth, so it /v/ very readily disappears in the following /b/.

   - Note that *been* is not used this way in negative statements.
   - Note that in some dialects *been* is also used as an alternative past form.

   All of these uses are non-standard and should not be emulated by learners in ***any*** register, even the most casual speech: speakers of a dialect in which one of these uses is standard may suspect you of mocking their speech. Stick to the standard forms.
2. Dialects which employ *ain't* use it for both *{is / are / am} not* and *{have / has} not*. *Ain't been* thus represents *haven't been* or, as in your example, *hasn't been*.

Comment: 1. What does _emulated by learners in any register_ mean? 2. I do not use AAVE dialect to mock anything; I happen to listen hip-hop which has made me use this dialect. I'll try not to use it as far as I could. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: *Emulate* means *imitate* or *copy*. *Registers* are the various styles of speaking and writing appropriate in various situations and genres.

Comment: I included that remark because some learners believe that they should strain to imitate the speech of the people they are talking with, and in some cases that is not a good idea. Most teenagers, for instance, resent their parents' and teachers' attempts to use teenage slang.

Comment: Any chance of a bit of support [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218058/parts-of-speech-and-functions-bob-made-a-book-collector-happy-the-other-day)? (An answer even? :D)

Comment: @Araucaria I voted to open; but you yourself are far more competent to answer this than I am. You're a widely-read pro-in-training, I'm just a sporadically-read amateur.

Comment: "Been" can also be used as an informal abbreviation of "Have you been", as in a question like "Been to the shops lately?" This usage is reasonably common here in Australia, and I have English friends who use "been" this way to.

Answer (score 4):

In the podcast "Is Black English a Dialect or a Language?" (part of *Slate*'s "Lexicon Valley" series), presenter Mike Vuolo and linguist Walter Wolfram explain that African-American English has a rich system of verb tense which is different from Standard English.

So, for example, “she been talking” means "she has been talking"; whereas “she BEEN talking”, with stress on the "been", means "she has been talking for a long time and she still is talking".

Similarly, “she talking” means "she is talking”; and “she be talking” means "she is usually talking".

If you're an English-language learner, you wouldn't want to emulate this dialect. It might be perceived that you are trying to parody or criticise those non-Standard language features.

Do check out the podcast and its transcription if you can. The informal, back-and-forth conversational style might be a bit hard going for a non-native speaker. But it changed my mind. I stopped seeing those features of black speech as degenerate or wrong. Though be aware that most speakers of Standard English or other dialects will judge you that way if you write "I been learnin' English on da StackExchange"!

http://www.slate.com/articles/podcasts/lexicon_valley/2012/02/lexicon_valley_is_black_english_a_dialect_or_a_language_.html

As for "ain't", I might try to address that separately.

Comment: Oh, I just read StoneyB's answer and its comments more fully, and realised that I also wrote "emulate". Sorry. His phrase "may suspect you of mocking their speech" is better than mine, also.

Comment: No need to apologise, I, now know the meaning of emulate. The problem with me is that I do not emulate this dialect rather I do not even now which dialect I use sometimes.(+1 and thank you for your answer, though :-) )

Comment: Is AAVE consider bad!!? I found it a great language and I am very curious to learn it. I live in India(Punjab), and I use "Doabi" dialect of "Punjabi". I can almost understand all other dialects of "Punjabi" as well. Here non-Punjabi's consider Punjabi a cool language. Isn't it good to use a dialect rather than the standard language? I find myself very delightful by knowing and using multiple languages and their dialects.

Comment: I'm not American, so my only exposure to AAVE is through USA TV and music.

Comment: It's good to understand, but there are issues of race and class to be careful of, too.  Most non-linguists wouldn't recognise AAVE as a distinct language variant with its own rules. Usually we are brought up with language in a prescriptive manner: school teaches you to speak and write "properly", and anyone who doesn't is "uneducated".  You may have an advantage coming from somewhere with a diversity of languages and dialects.

Answer (score 1):

Been there, done that.

Regarding "ain't been": in this case "ain't" is not short for "isn't" but indeed for "haven't".

"Been" on its own actually sounds less wrong than combined with a pronoun.  "Been busy, didn't get to it" is sort-of perfectly fine telegraph-style speech whereas "I been busy" sounds like slang.  Doesn't save any syllables over "I've been busy" either.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer, no. It's bad practice both formally and informally. You can however contract it. "I've been" is fine.

Comment: Reason for downvote please?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you didn't answer the OP's question *"Please explain me in simple language, what does I been mean and when is it used."* The phrase "I been" is not formally correct, but it is widely understood as an informal abbreviation of "I have been".